# What is the correct pattern to define a class that accepts a const and non-const object without violating const correctness?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

There are a number of obvious problems with this class and it is meant to illustrate the problem rather than demonstrate working code.

```
#include <list>

template<typename T>
class OnlyLists {
private:
   const std::list<T>* p_list;
   
public:
   OnlyLists(std::list<T>* list) : p_list(list) { }
   OnlyLists(const std::list<T>* list) : p_list(list) { }
   
   void modifiesList() {
      const_cast<std::list<T>*>(p_list)->clear();
   }
   
   size_t viewsList() const {
      return p_list->size();
   }
};

int main() {
   const std::list<int> const_list;
   
   // Constness is preserved
   const OnlyLists<int> a(&const_list);
   
   // Constness is discarded
   OnlyLists<int> b(&const_list);
   
   // Constness is discarded (another inherited problem)
   b = a;
   
   return 0;
}
```

I want to create a class that can view and modify a particular object (a list in this example). Its methods are exposed such that only the non-`const` ones can modify the list. The problem is that this constness on the methods only relates to whether the `OnlyLists` object is `const`. And if I accept a `const list<T>*` without also declaring the `OnlyLists` object as `const` then I can modify the list when I shouldn't.

It's possible to work around this by making the constructors private and making object creation a static method to ensure constness but this approach throws away public constructors entirely and is instead an anti-pattern. Additionally, keeping only one pointer `p_list` would already requires constness to be cast away when calling any method that would modify the list.

What is the correct pattern in C++ where I want one class to be able to view and modify another object like this?

The only solution that I can see is that any class which accepts both `const` and non-const types can only provide a const view. But the only issue here is with the object construction; the actual interface already protects the object from modification.

I thought about moving the entire `list` type into the template but this seems redundant if the class already accepts only lists. If I move the entire container into the template then constraints would need to be added to ensure that it is a list, etc. This seems overly complex when the constructor already limits itself to accepting only lists.

Comment: Do you want to have const lists and non-const lists in the same `OnlyLists`, or have it templated so one `OnlyLists` can only deal with non-const lists and a different one is needed for mutable lists?

Comment: Having a single class would be easier to maintain but if templatizing it with two different implementations is a solution then that would be acceptable.

Comment: "such that only the const ones can modify the list" -- are you missing a negation there?

Comment: You are correct. I've fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Since `OnlyLists` has reference semantics in the same way as `std::unique_ptr`, the usual practice is to control mutation using the constness of the template parameter:

- `OnlyLists<T>` can store a pointer to `std::list<T>`, and
- `OnlyLists<const T>` can accept a pointer to either `std::list<T>` or `const std::list<T>`, but will always store a pointer to `const std::list<T>`, and permit only `const` operations on the list.

The `modifiesList()` method might not be defined for `OnlyLists<const T>`, or it might be defined but cause a compilation error if instantiated (used).

Example:

```
template<typename T>
class OnlyLists {
private:
   std::list<T>* p_list;
   
public:
   OnlyLists(std::list<T>* list) : p_list(list) { }
   
   void modifiesList() {
      p_list->clear();
   }
   
   size_t viewsList() const {
      return p_list->size();
   }
};

// This is a partial specialization for the case where T is const
template<typename T>
class OnlyLists<const T> {
private:
   std::list<T> const* p_list;
   
public:
   OnlyLists(std::list<T> const* list) : p_list(list) { }
   
   size_t viewsList() const {
      return p_list->size();
   }
};
```

The issue of how to avoid duplication of `viewsList` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: A `const list<T>` is not the same as a `const list<const T>`.

Comment: @Zhro For value-semantic containers such as `std::list`, const-qualified template parameters aren't used. In other words, you don't need to support `std::list<const T>`. Only `const std::list<T>`.

Comment: Would you please clarify this with an example?

Comment: @Zhro Sure: if I want to write a function that takes a list of ints by reference but can't modify the elements, I might use the parameter type `const std::list<int>&`, but never `std::list<const int>&`, because the latter is not allowed by the standard library anyway.

Comment: I mean an example for your answer. I don't understand how to implement what you've described. My attempts have failed with the constness being discarded. Does this form have a name?

Comment: @Zhro see edits.

Comment: I see how it works now. This is confusing to read as the template specifies `const int` but `int` is not actually `const`. Is this an abuse of template specialization? I wouldn't understand what is happening without looking at the class definition.

Comment: @Zhro Well, my suggestion is what I personally would do. It makes sense to me, based on my understanding of constness for value-semantic and reference-semantic class templates. If you find this too confusing, you can come up with a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

C++17 solution:

If you're willing to modify your syntax a bit, you could add a `bool modifiable` template parameter to `OnlyLists`, create a partial specification for `modifiable = false` and introcude class template argument deduction ([CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)) to deduce the value of `modifiable` given the constructor parameters:

```
template<typename T, bool modifiable>
class OnlyLists
{
public:
    using ListType = std::list<T>;

    OnlyLists(ListType* list) : p_list(list) { }

    void modifiesList() {
        p_list->clear();
    }

    size_t viewsList() const {
        return p_list->size();
    }

private:
    ListType* p_list;
};

template<typename T>
class OnlyLists<T, false>
{
public:
    using ListType = std::list<T> const;

    OnlyLists(ListType* list) : p_list(list) { }

    size_t viewsList() const {
        return p_list->size();
    }

private:
    ListType* p_list;
};

// modifiable should be true if and only if the type the pointer points to is non-const
template<typename ListType>
OnlyLists(ListType*) -> OnlyLists<typename ListType::value_type, !std::is_const_v<ListType>>;
```

```
int main()
{
    std::list<int> non_const_list;
    const std::list<int> const_list;

    auto a = OnlyLists(&const_list); // a has type OnlyLists<int, false>

    a.viewsList();
    a.modifiesList(); // compiler error

    // Constness is discarded
    auto b = OnlyLists(&non_const_list); // b has type OnlyLists<int, true>

    b.viewsList();
    b.modifiesList();

    a = b; // compiler error

    decltype(b) c(nullptr);
    c = b; // Ok. Uses auto-generated a copy assignment operator

    return 0;
}
```